# When outputting content using wpcf7_mail_sent hook, form fails to complete sent message

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, hook

In WordPress, I'm using wpcf7 hooks to execute code in association with Contact Form 7, both before and after form submission. For example, I use

```
add_action("wpcf7_before_send_mail", "twilloSendMessage",10,1);
```

...to send an sms via Twilio before the email is sent. Works great.

Then I want to do some things after the mail is sent, and I use

```
// define the wpcf7_mail_sent callback 
function action_wpcf7_mail_sent( $contact_form ) { 
    // make action magic happen here... 
    $x = 1 + 1; // Operations like this don't cause the form submission to hang
    echo "test"; // ...but when I try outputting to the form page, "message sent" hangs.
}; 

// add the action 
add_action( 'wpcf7_mail_sent', 'action_wpcf7_mail_sent', 10, 1 );
```

The "wpcf7_mail_sent" seems to work, in as much as I can put code in my custom function *action_wpcf7_mail_sent*, where the code seems to execute. But if I try to output text in the "after send" function, the little spinning GIF keeps spinning, the "Your message has been sent" message box never appears, and no text will output on the screen.

Note: Nothing will be logged in the error.log
Note: Console shows no java script errors (none relating to Contact Form 7).

I'm pretty sure this means the javascript used to produce the "message sent" content does not actually complete BEFORE the wpcf7_mail_sent executes, and that something about putting html or text content in the hook callback interferes with the javascript. So, how can I use the wpcf7_mail_sent hook to output something independent of the CF7 message sent process?

[image]

Comment: As I think about this, php scripts will have executed before the page loads. CF7, however, submits a form in ajax fashion, and submitting the form doesn't redirect the client to an action page. I'm wondering if the only way to output to the form page AFTER submission is by invoking some kind of java script from within the  action_wpcf7_mail_sent function, in order to modify the DOM.

Comment: you mean "test" is not echo after successfully mail sent ?

Comment: @Dhruv correct, "test" does not echo, and even trying to output any content will cause the spinning GIF to keep spinning, and the message sent text will not output.

Comment: Looks like the solution is to add java script to the footer of the template. There is a js function analog to the php wpcf7_mail_sent called wpcf7mailsent, and when I add this code: `<script>
// Onsend contact form 7
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) { 
    setTimeout(function(){
        alert("???");
    }, 2500);

}, false );
</script>` ... everything works.